# bouncy castle provider jar for j2me

Tags: encryption, java-me, cryptography, java, bouncycastle

i'm new both with encryption and j2me. It may be a stupid question but where do i get a provider from bouncy castle to use with j9 vm? Isn't one just like the ones for jdk4,5,6(like  bcprov-jdk16-145.jar)?
I'm quite confused because as i've seen on bouncycastle's website, for j2me there is only that lightweight api but no provider api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no provider because the J2ME, now called JME, does not not support the JCE. You'll have to use the lightweight API.